# kwargs parsing best practice

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Is there a more compact/efficient way of doing this?

```
    for key in kwargs:
        if key == 'log':
            self.log = kwargs[key]
        elif key == 'bin':
            self.bin = kwargs[key]
        elif key == 'pid':
            self.pid = kwargs[key]
        elif key == 'conf':
            self.conf = kwargs[key]
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To achieve exactly what you asked for, you could use

```
for key in ('log', 'bin', 'pid', 'conf'):
    if key in kwargs:
        setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
```

or

```
self.__dict__.update((key, kwargs[key])
                     for key in ('log', 'bin', 'pid', 'conf')
                     if key in kwargs)
```

However, I would generally prefer something like this:

```
def f(log=None, bin=None, pid=None, conf=None):
    self.log = log
    self.bin = bin
    self.pid = pid
    self.conf = conf
```

While this is still somewhat repetitive, the code is really easy to read.  All attributes are intialized regardles of whether the corresponding keyword argument is passed in, and the signature of the function clearly documents the arguments and there defaults.

Comment: Nice! Could be even shorter with default value: `for key in (...): setattr(self, key, kwargs.get(key))`

Comment: @pajton: Of course, but I tried to stay as close to the OP's code as possible.

Comment: @pajton Why is the `if key in kwargs:` line removed in your suggestion? Why not check `if key in kwargs`?

Comment: It's not needed if it's OK to have a default value for these params. `kwargs.get(key)` will return `None` if the key is not present

Comment: There's also kwargs.pop(key[, default]) when kwargs are to be forwarded to internal calls. This one raises a key error though if key not found and default not given, so kwargs.pop(key, None) makes sense

Comment: @SvenMarnach I like the first example but how do I achieve the same functionality if I have a standalone function? I don't have self defined, hence I get an error '    setattr(self, key, kwargs[key]) NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: @Valentyn For a simple function, you don't need to assign the arguments to fields in `self`, so the whole question makes little sense for that case. I would definitely go with defaults for the arguments in that case, like in the last example, just without the assignments.

Answer (score 29):

```
self.log = kwargs.get('log', default_log)
self.bin = kwargs.get('bin', default_bin)
self.pid = kwargs.get('pid', default_pid)
self.conf = kwargs.get('conf', default_conf)
```

This has the additional advantage that `self.log` is assigned in any case (`AttributeError` means your code is broken as hell, nothing more. Always make sure everything is always assigned.). Without extra `self.log = default_log` lines. You can omit the default to get `None`.

Comment: I found this useful over `setattr` when i had to access `kwargs` outside of class ex)  Module Level

Answer (score 10):

If the key provided in `get()` is not in the dictionary the result is `None`.

```
self.log = kwargs.get('log')
self.bin = kwargs.get('bin')
self.pid = kwargs.get('pid')
self.conf = kwargs.get('conf')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for k,v in kwarg.iteritems():
   setattr(self, k, v)
```

In which `setattr(self, "bin", "val")` is like calling `self.bin = "val"`

However it is more desirable to have a whitelist like @Sven Marnach has.

Answer (score 2):

```
for k,v in kw.items():
   setattr(self, k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`

Comment: This can be very dangerous and is hacky either way.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is:

```
for key in ('log', 'bin', 'pid', 'conf'):
    setattr(self, key, kwargs.get(key, None))
```

In this mode, all attributes are initialized.

When I have a large number of attributes, I prefer to create a list to be easier to read like this:

```
kwargs_list = [
    "log",
    "bin",
    "pin",
    "conf"
]

for key in kwargs_list:
    setattr(self, key, kwargs.get(key, None))
```